# Radeon HD 7770 Ubuntu 12.04 installation problem

Tags: 12.04, radeon

I try to install ubuntu 12.04.5 but it always says 
"The system is running in low-graphic mode" after I clicked OK it says "Stand by one minute while the display restarts" but after waiting 5 minutes nothing happen but only shows black screen.. Is there any fix on this?